# FTP-Framework - Downloading file async - Callback, Delegate, Thread, BackgroundWorker, Exception inner Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I'm writing a FTPS-Framework. The user (programmer that uses my framework) should can download a file async (in another `Thread`). So, my big problem is, that the programmer cannot handle the `Exception`s throwed inside the `DownloadFile`-Method in the transfer-`Thread`:
- When I demand an `AsyncCallback` for telling the program that the download transfer is finish, how can "he" handling `Exception`s (from his `Thread`)?
- The `BackgroundWorker` has the same problem, furthermore the programmer have to give me a `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(object, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been two options for exposing an async API since .NET 2.0:

[The Asynchronous Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - favoured for more backend / library code.

[The Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) - favoured when your code will be used in a UI.

In .NET 4, you now also have the "Task-based Asynchronous Pattern" ( TAP ):

[Simplify Asynchronous Programming with Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff959203.aspx)

If you can, I would choose the TAP - it is the best of the three and solves problems like exception handling.

Comment: You're welcome. Have you read [Joe Albahari's free ebook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)?

Comment: In many articles is written that an `Exception` will be rethrown when I use the `EndInvoke`-method. But my DownloadFile-method don't wait, is throws the `Exception` in the Thread that I can't control and global `Exception` is a bad idea in this case. I thought the `Exception` can "wait" until I call `EndInvoke` an throws it there ???